# How to set a Java web filter pattern to match specify url?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jsf-2.2

I trying do understand why my web filter do not match a specify url pattern in my web aplication. I have implemented following filter:

```
 @WebFilter(filterName = "NewFilter", urlPatterns = {"/placowka/*"})
 public class NewFilter implements Filter
```

and i would like to execute a filter when following url pattern will approch to my server:

```
 http://localhost:8080/placowka/1
 http://localhost:8080/placowka/2
 .....
 http://localhost:8080/placowka/200
```

but filter not executed. When i change filter pattern to something like this:

```
 @WebFilter(filterName = "NewFilter", urlPatterns = {"/placowka"})
 public class NewFilter implements Filter
```

without

```
 /*
```

and I use a following url requests:

```
 http://localhost:8080/placowka
 http://localhost:8080/placowka
 .....
 http://localhost:8080/placowka
```

it works!

Soo why a that part of pattern /* of /placowka/* not match any character after /placowka

i would add here the following informations:

- I use glasfish with jsf 2.2.
- In my glasfish-web.xml file i have set context-root to /

  ```
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  ```

so my web application is under

```
  http://localhost:8080
```

not under

```
   http://localhost:8080/name_of_application
```

Answer (score 0):

Is seems you are using wildcard * as a string, try replacing string with regular expression + as pattern placowka/+ for your requirement.
for reference try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html